# WinForms databind to collection property (such as count)

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I want to databind to a collection property, such as Count.

in general, when I data bind I specify data member for the object property in the collection, not for the actual properties collection itself exposes.

for example, I have a list of custom objects. I show them in datagridview. but I also want to show their total count using a separate label. is there a way to do this through databinding?

I imagine that somehow I need to force PropertyManager to be used, instead of CurrentyManager?

I get the following exception. Notice that DataSource is collection and has TotalValue property.

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column TotalValue on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetBindableComponent(IBindableComponent value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data source is implementing the `IList` interface, like the `BindingList` does, the binding is trying to bind to a property of the elements inside the list.

Imagine you have a list of `string` items, then there is no property called `Count` for a single element.

Wrap your list to a class which is delegatingt the `Count` property without implementing the `IList` interface and fire a `PropertyChanged` event when the `BindingList` fires a `ListChanged` event.

```
class CountWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IBindingList bindingList;

    public CountWrapper(IBindingList bindingList)
    {
        this.bindingList = bindingList;

        bindingList.ListChanged += BindingList_ListChanged;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return bindingList.Count; }
    }

    private void BindingList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the `Count` property like so:

```
myLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", new CountWrapper(myObjectList), "Count");
```

This is possible for other properties also, just use a specific wrapper for your specific class. If your class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for its own properties, you only have to listen to that event and relay it also.

```
class MyListWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly MyList bindingList;

    public MyListWrapper(MyList bindingList)
    {
        this.bindingList = bindingList;

        bindingList.ListChanged += BindingList_ListChanged;
        bindingList.PropertyChanged+= BindingList_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return bindingList.Count; }
    }

    public int TotalCount
    {
        get { return bindingList.TotalCount; }
    }

    public string ReadWriteProperty
    {
        get { return bindingList.ReadWriteProperty; }
        set { bindingList.ReadWriteProperty = value; }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs ea)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, ea);
    }

    private void BindingList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
    }

    private void BindingList_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any reason you can't bind, say, a TextBox to `myObjectList.Count`, but 
`myobjectList` will need to implement `IBindingList<T>` either on its own if it's a custom collection with additional validation or by virtue of being of type `BindingList<T>`. `IBingingList<T>` contains events that fire when an object is added, removed, or changed within the collection.

See the MSDN Docs on [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx).  You'll probably want to use the former since the latter has a lot of members to implement.

Comment: @Josh Kodroff, actually myobjectList is a BindingList. I can bind to the properties of the items in the collection, but not to the property of the actual list (such as Count). for TextBox, I can specify property of the item in the collection and TextBox gets bound to the 1st item in the collection. When I try to bind to the List property I get an exception.

Comment: Can you add the exception you get to your post?

Comment: @Jesh Kodroff: added exception text

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the collection's Count by specifying collection.Count as the dataSource in the DataBindings.Add method.  The dataMember argument will be an empty string.

```
myLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObjectList.Count, string.Empty);
```

Comment: This doesn't bind the `myObjectList.Count` property. Instead it binds the integer value of `Count`property. Which means that binding will not update anymore. It is a static binding.